# I need to find all the AccountID from Account where the Phone number does not start with '00'

Tags: soql

I tried with this:

```
SELECT AccountID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NOT PHONE LIKE \'00%\'
```

It's giving me error:

> "No viable alterative character "\" "

Comment: Just as a heads up, this is going to be a non-selective query and will blow up if you have a large enough dataset.

Answer (score 2):

If you run query like this:

```
List<Account> accs = [ SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE NOT phone LIKE '00%'];
```

It will work and you don't need escape character in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The SOQL should be:

```
SELECT Id, Phone FROM Account WHERE (NOT Phone LIKE '00%')
```

I removed the `AccountId` field as there is no such field on `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a escape character inside a query. 
Additionally, you should just use the ID field, not the AccountId field.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NOT PHONE LIKE '00%'
```